# Catching Logoff (not power off) event on MAC using objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, unix

Can anybody tell me how can I catch user logoff event? I am able to catch poweroff event using  NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification notification. But it is not showing any difference in logoff and power off events. I want to catch log off and power off separately. I am able to catch the same on windows.

Comment: In what context? In an app? An agent? A daemon?

Comment: in a MAC application. Not daemon. If application is running at the time of shutdown or log off, it should capture it.

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to make sure your app is not participating in [sudden termination](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW28). If it is, then it can be killed at logout without any opportunity to react.

Now, when the user logs out, your app will get a `kAEQuitApplication` (`'quit'`) Apple Event. This will have the same effect as an invocation of `-[NSApplication terminate:]`. You can implement the application delegate method `-applicationShouldTerminate:` to be notified of the request to quit and control your app's response to it.

In that delegate method, you can use code like this to examine the quit event and learn the reason for the quit request:

```
    NSAppleEventManager* m = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* desc = [m currentAppleEvent];

    switch ([[desc attributeDescriptorForKeyword:kAEQuitReason] int32Value])
    {
        case kAELogOut:
        case kAEReallyLogOut:
            // log out
            break;
        case kAEShowRestartDialog:
        case kAERestart:
            // system restart
            break;
        case kAEShowShutdownDialog:
        case kAEShutDown:
            // system shutdown
            break;
        default:
            // ordinary quit
            break;
    }
```

Comment: this no longer works. `int32Value` returns nil. Is there any other way to do this? I want to listen to shutdown and restart events except logout event.

Comment: use `typeCodeValue` instead of `int32Value`